# Do I need to join every thread in my application ?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthread-join

I'm new with multi-threading and I need to get the whole idea about the "join" and do I need to join every thread in my application ?, and how does that work with multi-threading ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

no, you can detach one thread if you want it to leave it alone.
If you start a thread, either you detach it or you join it before the program ends, otherwise this is undefined behaviour.

To know that a thread needs to be detached you need to ask yourself this question: "do I want the the thread to run after the program main function is finished?". Here are some examples:

- When you do File/New you create a new thread and you detach it: the thread will be closed when the user closes the document Here you **don't need** to join the threads
- When you do a Monte Carlo simulation, some distributed computing, or any Divide And Conquer type algorithms, you launch all the threads and you need to wait for all the results so that you can combine them. Here you explicitly **need** to join the thread before combining the results

Comment: added this into my answer. Does that help you?

Comment: perfect, so choose one of the answer people provided to you and select it as the one you will follow to help future readers know which one helped you

Comment: you click on the number close to the answer you've chosen and something like "this is the best answer". One green checkup mark should appear after that

Comment: You didn't mention the situation where the target thread has already terminated. You do not *need* to call join() on that right ?

Answer (score 3):

Not joining a thread is like not `delete`ing all memory you `new`.  It can be harmless, or it could be a bad habit.

A thread you have not synchronized with is in an unknown state of execution.  If it is a file writing thread, it could be half way through writing a file and then the app finishes.  If it is a network communications thread, it could be half way through a handshake.

The downside to joining every thread is if one of them has gotten into a bad state and has blocked, your app can hang.

In general you should try to send a message to your outstanding threads to tell them to exit and clean up.  Then you should wait a modest amount of time for them to finish or otherwise respond that they are good to die, and then shut down the app.  Now prior to this you should signify your program is no longer open for business -- shit down GUI windows, respond to requests from other processes that you are shutting down, etc -- so if this takes longer than anticipated the user is not bothered.  Finally if things go imperfectly -- if threads refuse to respond to your request that they shut down and you give up on them -- then you should log errors as well, so you can fix what may be a symptom of a bigger problem.

The last time a worker thread unexpectedly hung I initially thought was a problem with a network outage and a bug in the timeout code.  Upon deeper inspection it was because one of the objects in use was `delete`d prior to the shutdown synchronization: the undefined behaviour that resulted just looked like a hang in my reproduction cases.  Had we not carefully joined, that bug would have been harder to track down (now, the right thing to do would have been to use a shared resource that we could not delete: but mistakes happen).

Answer (score 2):

> The pthread_join() function suspends execution of the calling thread
>   until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has
>   already terminated. On return from a successful pthread_join() call
>   with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to pthread_exit()
>   by the terminating thread is made available in the location referenced
>   by value_ptr. When a pthread_join() returns successfully, the target
>   thread has been terminated. The results of multiple simultaneous calls
>   to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread are undefined. If
>   the thread calling pthread_join() is canceled, then the target thread
>   will not be detached.

So [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) does two things:

1. Wait for the thread to finish.
2. Clean up any resources associated
   with the thread.

This means that if you exit the process without call to [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html), then (2) will be done for you by the OS (although it won't do thread cancellation **cleanup**), and (1) will not be done.

So whether you need to call [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) depends whether you need (1) to happen.

---

### Detached thread

If you don't need the thread to run, then you may as well [pthread_detach](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) it. A detached thread cannot be joined (so you can't wait on its completion), but its resources are freed automatically if it does complete.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to join every thread in my application ?

Not necessarily - depends on your design and OS.  Join() is actively hazardous in GUI apps - tend  If you don't need to know, or don't care, about knowing if one thread has terminated from another thread, you don't need to join it.

I try very hard to not join/WaitFor any threads at all.  Pool threads, app-lifetime threads and the like often do not require any explicit termination - depends on OS and whether the thread/s own, or are explicitly bound to, any resources that need explicit termination/close/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Threads can be either joinable or detached. Detached threads should not be joined. On the other hand, if you didn't join the joinable thread, you app would leak some memory and some thread structures. c++11 std::thread would call std::terminate, if it wasn't marked detached and thread object went out of scope without `.join()` called. See [pthread_detach](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) and [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html). This is much alike with processes. When the child exits, it will stay as zombee while it's creater willn't call `waitpid`. The reson for such behavior is that thread's and process's creater might want to know there exit code.

Update: if `pthread_create` is called with attribute argument equal to NULL (default attributes are used), joinable thread will be created. To create a detached thread, you can use attributes:

```
pthread_attr_t attrs;
pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
pthread_create(thread, attrs, callback, arg);
```

Also, you can make a thread to be detached by calling `pthread_detach` on a created one. If you will try to join with a detached thread, `pthread_join` will return `EINVAL` error code. glibc has a non portable extension `pthread_getattr_np` that allows to get attributes of a running thread. So you can check if thread is detached with `pthread_attr_getdetachstate`.